# javascript document.frmName undefined, had to use doucment.forms.frmName

Tags: javascript, forms, web-applications, document

So our company is in the process of converting webform websites to web applications so we can implement Azure Key Vault. A lot of these applications have javascript within the aspx. In one project particularly after converting to web application and implementing the AKV I received a issue of something broken.

```
function UpdateSuites(strFieldIDs, strFieldNames)
    {
        var frm = document.frmGrid;
        var all = document.all;
        frm.txtfieldIds.value       = strFieldIDs;
        frm.txtFieldNames.value     = strFieldNames;
        all.lblFieldNames.innerText = strFieldNames;
    }
```

All of sudden this line of code is throwing undefined

```
 var frm = document.frmGrid;
```

I updated it to be the following

```
var frm = document.forms.frmGrid;
```

And this resolved the issue, but we want to know why did this occur all of sudden?
All we did was migrate a website to a web application.
How does this break javascript?
The .Net Framework was 4.5, and now it's 4.8 during this migration

Comment: Has the website not been updated since 1999? That is old way or working with forms.

Comment: That javascript looks pretty obsolete.  Eventually it will completely stop working, see the large red label [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/all) for example.  I would suggest a rewrite using modern css selectors to get references to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector("#frmGrid")` or `document.getElementById("frmGrid")` is what you want.

Your attempts rely on elements with `id`s becoming global properties, which is a 20+ year old non-standard way of doing this.